# Cannot find the setter for attribute '{attribute}' with parameter type {type} on {View}

Tags: android, android-databinding

Have an problem with binding adapter. Here the code:

```
@BindingAdapter(value = {"menu", "menuItemClick"}, requireAll = false)
public static void setMenu(View view, int menu, PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener listener) {
    if (menu == 0 || menu == -1) {
        return;
    }

    view.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(), view);
        //Inflating the Popup using xml file
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(listener);
        popup.show();
    });
}
```

View in layout hierarchy:

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fields_edit_hint_length"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            app:menu="@{item.getTypesMenuRes()}"
            app:menuItemClick="@{item}"
            app:visible="@{item.value.length!= 0 &amp;&amp; !item.isFieldLocked()}"/>
```

Method getTypesMenuRes returns int, as in Binding Adapter

```
 public int getTypesMenuRes() {
    switch (type()) {
        case PhoneNumber:
            return R.menu.edit_fields_phone_types;
        case Email:
            return R.menu.edit_fields_email_types;
        default:
            return -1;
    }
}
```

but i get compile time erroe:

```
Error:(67, 29) Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:menu' with parameter type int on android.widget.FrameLayout.
```

I am using View instead of FrameLayout inside BindingAdapter, but it is allowed, because it is predeccessor of FrameLayout (and i did it many times before), and i absolutely not undersatand reason of this erroe. Can you advice me something?

Update:

I am switched lines

```
            app:menu="@{item.getTypesMenuRes()}"
            app:menuItemClick="@{item}"
```

and get the same error with app:menuItemClick. Tried to remove `requiredAll = false` , but did not helps too

Answer (score 1):

Found out. I was using BindingAdapter `android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu`; , but class Field was implementing `android.widget.PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener`; as result BindingAdapter was wrong and for different orders of fields in view in layout. And this error was natural